# Xubuntu Media plays at triple+ speed

Tags: audio, settings, xubuntu

Out of the blue today, I just booted my PC and Raspberry Pi like normal, with my PC running Xubuntu and my RPI running Raspbian, and on my PC at least ALL media is running at triple or higher speed. Youtube videos, mp3's and normal videos all run at triple speed. They also won't play any sound, and I am sure I have my speakers turned on and medium volume. On my windows 7 partition everything still works. Something like this has never happened to me before, and is obviously very strange. The only thing I can remember to have done is `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

I have looked at the following, but I don't have any sound settings anywhere. http://www.hanckmann.net/?q=high_speed_video_and_no_audio_in_linux

My Raspberry Pi can't play any sound for whatever reason so I wouldn't know about the RPI.

Obviously, my question is, how can I play media normally again?

/IP

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem but you can try what's suggested in this askubuntu question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/85216/videos-songs-and-all-media-playing-in-fast-forward

Comment: @slm I would try it, but as I noted in the OP I don't have any sound settings anymore, and I am not the most experienced linux user, so I don't really know where to get them(back).